# ESPG:27700 is displaying incorrect coordiantes

Tags: coordinate-system

I am new to GIS, so forgive me. I have set up a project using Open Street Map as my background, I have set the CRS to ESPG:27700 British National Grid, however the status bar is not displaying the coordinates correctly, and still says 000,000 is located on the intersection of Greenwich meridian and the equator...any thought how to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Which software are you working with?

Comment: Based off your wording I'm going to assume that you're using QGIS. Are you sure the project itself is set to 27700 and not just the data? Check what EPSG it says down the bottom right.

Comment: Yes i am using QGIS.

Comment: The project and the layer are both set to 27700 and it says that in the bottom corner. i have auto generated some x and y co-ordinates in Leicester and they have not come out in British National Grid, but in work grid